# parse json data in javascript show object-object

Tags: json

I'm parsing the following json data.

[{"id":"1","name":"vikash"}]
I'm using the following the jquery function to parse its value showing object-object msg in alert box.plz let me know how can I resolve this?

```
 function getid(id)
   {
 $.ajax({url:"page.php?id="+id, 
     success:function(result){
alert(result);
    var arr = $.parseJSON(result);

     $( arr).each( function( i, value ) {
    var ab=$( "input[name=" + i + "]" ).val( value );
     alert(ab);
    });

     }});                               
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid JSON

Guessing you mean either:
    [{"id":"1","name":"vikash"}]

or:
    {"id":"1","name":"vikash"}

Comment: sorry, I mean this [{"id":"1","name":"vikash"}]